# ¿Cómo cambiar un dato de una línea en particular de un archivo con Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo

Tengo un archivo con el siguiente contenido:

```
config interface 'lan'option type 'bridge'

option ifname 'eth0'

option proto 'static'

option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'

option netmask '255.255.255.0'

option ip6assign '60'


config interface 'wlan0'

option proto 'static'

option netmask '255.255.255.0'

option ipaddr '192.168.6.1'
```

Y necesito cambiar el valor de la ip en "option ipaddr" únicamente de "wlan0"

He intentando con lo siguiente:

```
newValue = "'192.168.1.50'"

for line in fileinput.FileInput("network", inplace=1):
    if line.startswith("option ipaddr "):
        new_line=line.replace(line, "option ipaddr " + newValue)
        print(new_line)
    else:
        print(line, end='')
```

Pero me cambia los valores en ambas interfaces, ¿Cómo podría editar únicamente la ip de wlan0? ¿Cómo puedo hacer algo como, si se encuentra "config interface 'wlan0' entonces edita "option ipaddr"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones, pero una muy simple es buscar previamente la linea con `config`, si la linea tiene la interfaz objetivo, sabemos que la siguiente linea con `option ipaddr` es la que debemos modificar. Para marcar cuando debe hacerse podemos usar una simple variable boleana que indique cuando ha sido encontrada la interfaz:

```
import fileinput


new_value = "192.168.1.50"
interface = "wlan0"

with fileinput.FileInput("network", inplace=True) as file:
    target = False
    for line in file:
        if  not target and line.startswith(f"config interface '{interface}'"):
            target = True
        elif target and line.startswith("option ipaddr "):
            line = f"option ipaddr '{new_value}'"
            target = False
        print(line, end="")
```

Comment: Probe el código pero sigue cambiando los valores para ambas interfaces :/

Comment: Cierto, en una edición de la pregunta eliminé parte del elif que no debía... Corregido.